# Down voting cards in Trello

Tags: trello

Here's a user story:

As a member of a planning team viewing a list of cards in order to vote on them, 
I want to be able to indicate a negative vote 
so that it's easier to tell between cards that are just "not currently high priority" from cards that members actively want to close.

Other than adding comments, there doesn't seem to be a way to apply and tally negative votes on cards. There is no way to down vote currently, right?

UPDATED:

Possible workaround inspired on one of the answers to this: [Is it possible to add story points and velocity tracking to Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/19395/19306)

Each person who wants to downvote can increment a number in the title, possibly prefixed, like "NO(2). This is the title" (meaning this has 2 downvotes). I still don't think this is optimal, but at least it is on the "front" of the card.

Answer (score 2):

Current there is no downvote functionality in Trello.

As a workaround, perhaps you could use a label like "Candidate for Deletion"?  Then (as you say) folks could use comments to indicate that the support closing the card.

Comment: I'll mull this over and see what happens. I imagine the shape of the board will evolve and the way we use it is probably largely informed by how we use other tools, like StackExchange (where you can downvote).

Comment: Yeah, we may add an up/down voting plugin in the future; we were trying to keep the voting system pretty simple.